# Getting a count of the number of successful updates

Tags: scala

I've got a Scala function that inserts an entry into a MySQL database. I'd like to keep a count of the number of entries that were successfully inserted and return that to the caller. Basically, it looks like this:

```
def putInDB(lstItems: List[String]): Int = {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
  val dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/somedb?" "user=someuser&password=somepass")
  val stmt = dbConn.createStatement
  var insertCount = 0 //Not sure if this is the right way
  lstItems.foreach { l =>
    val res = stmt.executeUpdate("insert ignore into mytable ... ")
    if (res > 0) insertCount = insertCount + 1  // Nor this
  }
  insertCount
}
```

I'm not sure if the `var insertCount` and the way I update the variable in the loop is correct. My Functional Programming skills are a bit rusty; what is the right way to maintain a count if I want to do it in a "Functional" style? i.e., use immutable variable and avoid an `if` statement of the kind I've used.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do `lstItems.map(l => stmt.executeUpdate("...")).sum`? :) I don't know exactly what `executeUpdate` returns, but I assume it's 'rows affected'.

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much what Shadowlands suggested. executeUpdate returns 0 or 1 but there are situations where it returns -1 as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (assuming executeUpdate always returns either 0 or 1):

```
lstItems.map(stmt.executeUpdate).sum
```

Actually, better would be:

```
lstItems.map(stmt.executeUpdate).count(_ > 0)
```

Comment: `Statement.executeUpdate` returns a row count, so it might be greater than 1, so your second choice is the right one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say :

```
val count =  lstItems.foldLeft(0) { (sum, item) => 
    val res = stmt.executeUpdate("insert ignore into mytable ... ")
    if (res > 0 ) sum + 1
    else sum
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the `if then else` block still makes me wonder. I like Shadowlands' answer better.

Comment: Note that `foldleft` only goes through the list once, while the `map.count` solution does it twice ( first time with `map` to create an intermediate list and then with `count`), in case efficiency is a concern.

Comment: Hmm, that's a very valid point. Thanks, I'll keep it in mind. I'm currently only expecting not more than a 1000 entries (worst case) so if that becomes a problem, I'll try this out! :)